# How to force Angular 's "require" to support array input names.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, required

I am adding a form input field required doesn't work here

```
<input name="ResellerAddress[address_1]" ng-model="reseller.address" required>
<div class="field_error_row" id="ResellerAddress_address_1_error"  ng-show="addressForm.ResellerAddress[address_1].$error.required"><span>This is an error</span></div>
```

But does work here

```
<input name="address" ng-model="reseller.address" required>
<div class="field_error_row" id="ResellerAddress_address_1_error"  ng-show="addressForm.address.$error.required"><span>This is an error</span></div>
```

Is there a way to force required to support array input fields?

Comment: are you sure you have defined 'address_1' somewhere?

Comment: `ResellerAddress[address_1]` seems not defined.

Comment: Isn't it defined in the input's name?